# How to embed multiline LaTeX equations into Wygwam box

Tags: wygwam

As an example, if I want to use something like:

```
\begin{eqnarray} a &=& b ( d + c) + c \\
 && bd + bc + c \\
a &=& bd + c(b + 1)\end{eqnarray}
```